# How to make events line up in Bootstrap Calendar

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

When using Bootstrap Calendar http://bootstrap-calendar.azurewebsites.net/index-bs3.html the events don't line up when in the Week view.

For example if you have 2 events:
- Today 10am to 11am
- Tomorrow 10am to 11am

In the week view, they look like a staircase, one, the next one below... not lined up.

Thanks[image]

I already tried different times, etc..  documentation is limited and I am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: If you inspect the HTML of the demo you can see that each event is on its own line, inside a block-level div. You'd probably have to hack up the plugin to change that. The logic for determining which elements to combine could get pretty twisty.

Comment: I can't hack it.. this is for a fast prototype...  Any recommendations on a simple to use Week view pluging of any kind?

Comment: @isherwood .... what about simply stacking them all valign top.. I don't really care for them showing "chronologically" correct (the ones at 10am higher than the ones at 2pm.. etc)  meaning.. simply all activities for the day just to show valigned top...  any suggestion on doing that?

Comment: That won't work. As Egidius points out below, you'd need to restructure the HTML. I suggest an alternative plugin with more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

The events don't line up because they are wrapped in a div witht he following class:

```
.cal-row-fluid {
    width: 100%;
}
```

This causes the div to stretch as wide as its parent is.

A sollution would be to place the contents of one event into the parent of the other. Like this:

```
<div class="cal-row-fluid">
    <div class="cal-cell1 cal-offset4 day-highlight dh-event-success" data-event-class="event-success">
        <a href="http://www.example.com/" data-event-id="297" class="cal-event-week event297">This is success event</a>
    </div>
        <div class="cal-cell1 cal-offset4 day-highlight dh-event-success" data-event-class="event-success">
    <a href="http://www.example.com/" data-event-id="276" class="cal-event-week event276">Short day event</a>
    </div>
</div>
```